# Find not common users in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables. I want to get specific users in table 1 that are not in table2, table3, table4 and table5. Can someone please help me :)

```
table1(userid,discount)
table2(userid,discount)
table3(userid,discount)
table4(userid,discount)
table5(userid,discount)
```

Comment: You should add some examples. What's your input and what is the expected output?

Comment: So what exactly is the requirement? To produce a list of users that only exist in one table? That exist in only 1-4 out of the five?

Comment: I want to get specific users in table1 that are not in table2, table3, table4 and table5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query:

```
SELECT userid
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM (
    SELECT userid
    FROM table2
    UNION 
    SELECT userid
    FROM table3
    UNION 
    SELECT userid
    FROM table4
    UNION 
    SELECT userid
    FROM table5) AS t2
  WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid)
```

returns all users of `table1` that don't exist in any of the other tables.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5e7c/1)

If you also want, say, all users of `table2` that don't exist in any of the other tables, then you can modify the above query so as to return users from `table2` and perform a `UNION` between these two queries:

```
SELECT userid
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM (
    SELECT userid
    FROM table2
    UNION 
    SELECT userid
    FROM table3
    UNION 
    SELECT userid
    FROM table4
    UNION 
    SELECT userid
    FROM table5) AS t2
  WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid)

UNION ALL

SELECT userid
FROM table2 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM (
    SELECT userid
    FROM table1
    UNION 
    SELECT userid
    FROM table3
    UNION 
    SELECT userid
    FROM table4
    UNION 
    SELECT userid
    FROM table5) AS t2
  WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5e7c/3)

The above can easily be extended so as to incorporate users from all tables. But, I have to admit, it becomes quite verbose !

Comment: @Giogros can you please tell me how to find the common values of table 1, 2 and 3, that are not in table 4 and 5? Please help me to find an answer :)

Comment: @Volka Well, that's a different question and it is generally discouraged answering questions in comments. You can post a different question here is SO if you want to get an answer.

Comment: As you suggested I created a new question :) Please help me to find the answer :) [link to the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340184/find-common-users-in-multiple-tables-in-sql)