# Find common users in multiple tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables.

I want to get common users in table 1, 2 and 3 that are not in table 4 and 5.

Can someone please help me :)

**Tables**

```
table1(userid,discount)

table2(userid,discount)

table3(userid,discount)

table4(userid,discount)

table5(userid,discount)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, left join on the table rows to omit:

```
select *
from   table1 a
join   table2 b on (a.userid = b.userid)
join   table3 c on (a.userid = c.userid)
left join table4 d on (a.userid = d.userid)
left join table5 e on (a.userid = e.userid)
where d.userid is null and e.userid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the users common to tables 1, 2, 3 is easy -- just do an inner join. To get all of those users which are not in tables 4 or 5, you could test for their non-existence in these tables in the `where` clause.

```
select *
from table1
  join table2 on table1.userid = table2.userid
  join table3 on table1.userid = table3.userid
where
  not exists (select * from table4 where table4.userid = table1.userid)
  and not exists (select * from table5 where table5.userid = table1.userid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableA a
JOIN   tableB b ON (a.userid = b.userid)
JOIN   tableC c ON (a.userid = c.userid)
LEFT JOIN tableD d ON (a.userid = d.userid)
LEFT JOIN tableE e ON (a.userid = e.userid)
WHERE d.userid IS NULL and e.userid IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT t1.userid, t2.userid, t2.userid, t4.userid, t5.userid
 FROM table1 t1
 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.userid = t1.userid)
 LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON (t3.userid = t1.userid)
 LEFT JOIN table4 t4 ON (t4.userid = t1.userid)
 LEFT JOIN table5 t5 ON (t5.userid = t1.userid)
GROUP BY t1.userid
HAVING t1.userid IS NOT NULL 
     AND t2.userid IS NOT NULL
     AND t3.userid IS NOT NULL
     AND t4.userid IS NULL
     AND t5.userid IS NULL
```